# CSS code for controlling spacing below a math equation in R bookdown

Tags: html, css, r, bookdown

In R Bookdown one can write mathematical equations, but I wonder how can one control the space below and above each of such elements in the css file?

In the html code, those containers appear as:

```
<p>
<span class="math display">
\[\begin{equation}Weighted \ average= \frac{(83*40)+(95*60)}{(40+60)}    \end{equation}\]
</span>
</p>
```

Unfortunately, that element is too close to the text that follows below and above. I would like to increase that space using the css file..can that be done?
If I use the code below it does not work. I have tried different combinations of that with no luck.

```
.math display{
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E47zb.png)

Comment: Could you please display a picture of the problem?

Comment: Use line height

Comment: I added a figure. what I need is more space where the red arrows are.  Like increasing the height above and below the container.